# Is there a way to safely remove IE and MS Edge from windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge

I put a bunch of Plugins into Firefox to Prevent myself from visiting reddit and 4chan. Problem is, that Plugin isn't available on IE or Edge so I Keep relapsing.
Is there a way to block or get rid of IE and Edge, just so much that its a bit of a hassle to undo?

Comment: Sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) to me. There's a Mac app called 'self control', no doubt there's a Windows equivalent, just search it out.

Comment: Not really, since the problem I have is "how do I block Edge on my own machine" and the problem in the background is just context. What you mean is "How do I load an ajax script using css?" Thanks tough

Comment: Your problem is "how do I block certain sites?" It has absolutely nothing to do with uninstalling a browser. That's the X of your Y.

Comment: Well I don't care about edge either way and already know that theres no good site blocking on edge

Answer (score -3):

Figured it out.
Just go to C:/System-Apps/Microsoft-Edgexxxxxxxxxx
and rename it to something like
C:/System-Apps/Microsoft-Edgexxxxxxxxxx_LOL

Gets rid of it